# Get and Set Property FxCop Rule

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, fxcop, static-code-analysis

So I'm writing a custom Fxcop rule to insure that whenever a Get or a Set method are utilized, there is also a GetProperty or a SetProperty in it. How would I be able to test this.

Example:

```
public double Seconds
{
   get { return this.GetProperty(() => this.Seconds); }
   set { this.SetProperty(() => this. Seconds, value); }
}
```

Rather than this:

```
public double Seconds
{
    get { return Seconds; }
    set { Seconds = value; }
}
```

So far, I can find every instance of a get or a set with this code. I just need help catching if there is actually a GetProperty or a SetProperty.

```
    public override ProblemCollection Check( Member member )
    {
        ProblemCollection Problems = this.Problems;

        var method = member as Method;

        if ( method != null )
        {
            if ( method.Name.Name.Contains( "get_" ) || method.Name.Name.Contains( "set_" ) )
            {
                Resolution resolu = GetResolution( new[] { member.ToString() } );
                Problems.Add( new Problem( resolu ) );
                return Problems;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm curious - what is the advantage of this rule (as it is new to me)?

Comment: well we have GetProperty and SetProperty defined in our new framework which we are pushing out to our developers and we want this to be a standard.

Comment: Do you mean a `GetProperty`/`SetProperty` method available, or actually used? BTW, why doesn't your `SetProperty` method assign a value?

Comment: It seems a bit odd. You have added another, unnecessary level of indirection. What's wrong with "public double Seconds { get; set; }"? Much simpler. The compiler will auto-generate the get and set methods for you. Why add another level of get/set methods for no benefit? Have you profiled your method to see what the overhead is?

Comment: I think that you may be a bit confused. The GetProperty is a custom method in our framework that is called when the Get method is used.